# Python Dataframes not merging on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes, but for some reason it's throwing `KeyError: Player_Id`

I'm trying to merge on `Striker_Id` and `Player_Id`

This is how my Dataframe looks like

[image]

Merge Code:

```
player_runs.merge(matches_played_by_players,left_on='Striker_Id',right_on='Player_Id',how='left')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, from looking at your problem, it seems like you're trying to merge on the indexes, but you treat them as columns? Try changing your merge code a bit -

```
player_runs.merge(matches_played_by_players,
                  left_index=True,
                  right_index=True,
                  how='left')
```

Furthermore, make sure that both indexes are of the *same type* (in this case, consider <s>`str`</s>`int`?)

```
player_runs.index = player_runs.index.astype(int)
```

And,

```
matches_played_by_players.index = matches_played_by_players.index.astype(int)
```

Comment: both indexes are of `Int64`, I ran your code, got a new error: `ValueError: left_index parameter must be of type bool, not <class 'str'>`

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri you should type `True`, not `"True"` :-)

Comment: worked! thanks, but we didn't define what is the index_name for left and right index, how did it know to join on them?

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri Specify that you want to join on the index. That's all the information that pandas needs to perform the merge :)

Answer (score 2):

you're basically merging on none existing columns. this is because `reset_index` creates a new data-frame rather than changing the data frame it's applied to. setting the parameter `inplace=True` when using reset_index should resolve this issue, alternatively merge on the index of each data-frame. i.e.

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left')
```

Comment: I was merely explaining the reason behind the error