# error when trying to merge by index on python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two panda data.frames by index but I get an empty data.frame.

I am following the solutions posted in this link [Python Dataframes not merging on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026254/python-dataframes-not-merging-on-index)

but it is not working,

These are my two data.frames

```
>>>norm_df.head()
                    eQTL-103  eQTL-105  eQTL-106  eQTL-111  eQTL-112  \
transcript_id                                                          
ENST00000456328.2  -0.418029 -0.418029 -0.418029 -0.418029  0.733977   
ENST00000488147.1   0.330873 -1.786156  0.562062  0.023212  0.380326   
ENST00000466430.5   1.128144 -1.914506 -0.589456 -0.430727 -0.796183   
ENST00000442987.3   1.446104 -0.508488  0.895780  0.306454  0.828465   
ENST00000494149.2   0.674490 -1.085325 -0.828465  0.116309 -0.186756   

                    eQTL-115  eQTL-126  eQTL-127  eQTL-131  eQTL-133  \
transcript_id                                                          
ENST00000456328.2   1.786156 -0.418029  1.382994 -0.418029  0.861634   
ENST00000488147.1   1.005170 -1.044409 -1.515564  1.324958  0.000000   
ENST00000466430.5   0.282216 -1.593219  0.828465  0.589456  0.430727   
ENST00000442987.3  -0.931003  0.258143  0.535083  1.786156 -0.210428   
ENST00000494149.2  -0.562062  0.306454 -0.861634  0.282216  0.430727     

                   eQTL-80   eQTL-85   eQTL-87   eQTL-94   eQTL-96   eQTL-97  
transcript_id                                                                   
ENST00000456328.2  -0.418029 -0.418029  1.005170 -0.418029 -0.418029 -0.418029  
ENST00000488147.1  -0.967422 -0.482248 -0.764710  0.895780  0.116309 -0.931003  
ENST00000466430.5   0.508488  0.023212 -0.931003 -0.562062  0.861634 -1.382994  
ENST00000442987.3  -1.914506  0.380326 -0.482248 -0.116309  0.674490 -1.005170  
ENST00000494149.2  -1.515564 -0.430727 -0.023212  0.617300  0.186756 -0.046436  

[5 rows x 107 columns]

>>> bed_template_df.head()

                    chr  start    end      transcript_id
transcript_id                                           
ENST00000456328.2  chr1  11868  11869  ENST00000456328.2
ENST00000450305.2  chr1  12009  12010  ENST00000450305.2
ENST00000488147.1  chr1  29569  29570  ENST00000488147.1
ENST00000619216.1  chr1  17435  17436  ENST00000619216.1
ENST00000473358.1  chr1  29553  29554  ENST00000473358.1
```

I have tried the `pd.merge`

```
 bed_df = pd.merge(bed_template_df, norm_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but the result is an empty data.frame

I have tried to set up the same type to both indexes

```
 norm_df.index = norm_df.index.astype(str)
 bed_template_df.index = bed_template_df.index(str)
```

But it doesn't work, when I specified the `how` in the merge command I get this result

```
>>> bed_df = pd.merge(bed_template_df, norm_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')

>>> bed_df.head()
                    chr  start  end transcript_id  eQTL-103  eQTL-105  
transcript_id                                                           
ENST00000456328.2   NaN    NaN  NaN           NaN -0.418029 -0.418029   
ENST00000488147.1   NaN    NaN  NaN           NaN  0.330873 -1.786156   
ENST00000466430.5   NaN    NaN  NaN           NaN  1.128144 -1.914506   
ENST00000442987.3   NaN    NaN  NaN           NaN  1.446104 -0.508488   
ENST00000494149.2   NaN    NaN  NaN           NaN  0.674490 -1.085325
```

It looks like python doesn't find the two indexes equal but I can see that `ENST00000456328.2` in `bed_template_df` exists in `norm_df`

Comment: You might check for leading or trailing spaces in the strings in your indices, see if your result is the same after using `strip()` on both DFs

Comment: can you check if the two indicies are the same?  norm_df.index.values == bed_template_df.index.values. If they are not the same than you can't merge them but you can concatenate them vertically and all your entries will be preserved

Comment: @FrancescoZambolin, no, they are not the same, results is `False` could you tell me how to concatenate them vertically?

Comment: @G.Anderson, you were right. There were some trailing spaces and after `norm_df.index=norm_df.index.str.strip()` it worked!!. Thanks

Comment: How should the final dataframe look like? I ask because I see that the index ENST00000456328.2 is common to both dataframes while the others are not. What columns should be present in the final dataframe?

Comment: @FrancescoZambolin, only the common in both dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to put an answer together.

1.Find indicies that are common in both dataframes:

```
common_id = set(norm_df.index.values).intersection(set(bed_template_df.index.values))
```

2.Merge the dataframes on common_id:

```
final_df = pd.merge(bed_template_df[common_id], norm_df[common_id], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This should work if I understood you right. It gives you a final dataframe that contains only indicies common to both norm_df and bed_template_df and all the columns from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution.

**An explanation of what I tried:** I created a data frame `final` from a CSV file in Excel, in which I filled in a column for the index. In python, I set the first column of `final` as the index. I had typed in the same values as the index I set on the data frame I wanted to merge with—I'll refer to this as `df1`. The result was an empty data frame. I then took my `df1` and exported it to CSV and loaded that back in as my `final` CSV. Using `final.index.values == df.index.values` [as mentioned by @Francesco Zambolin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56967339/3025856) gave `False` on every part of the index, even though the index for `final` was derived from an export of `df1`. I don't know why it's `False`.

**Solution:** I found a workaround on another post ([Create an empty data frame with index from another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176933/create-an-empty-data-frame-with-index-from-another-data-frame)). Using `final.index=df1.index`, I was able to create an index that was the same for both data frames. Only after that did the following finally work:

```
mergedfinal=final.merge(df1,left_index=True, right_index=True)
```